# Builder with support for nested objects

Tags: c#, delegates, builder

I am new to C# and programming in general and was trying to find out how to implement a builder that can support nested objects when I found the following question:
[Builder pattern with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480410/builder-pattern-with-nested-objects#)

The accepted solutions work but I realize I don't fully understand what is going on in the code.

Especially this part that is defining the Action:

```
public ReceiptBuilder WithItem(string text, Action<ReceiptItemBuilder> itemBuilder)
{
    var rib = new ReceiptItemBuilder(text);
    itemBuilder(rib);
    r.AddItem(rib.Build());
    return this;
}
```

Would be nice if someone could explain what happens during this call?

```
itemBuilder(rib);
```

Comment: `itemBuilder` is a `Action` delegate that takes a `ReceiptItemBuilder` which means it can be called like a method with the signature `void itemBuilder(ReceiptItemBuilder x)`.  Delegates are basically how you can pass functions in C#.

Comment: Have a look at these tutorials: [Delegates Level1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm) and [Delegates Level2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-delegates) and [Anonymous Methods Level1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_anonymous_methods.htm) and [Anonymous Methods Level2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-anonymous-method)

Comment: Also: [Action](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-action-delegate) and [Func](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-func-delegate)

Comment: @OlivierRogier don't forget [Predicate](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-predicate)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will for sure look into those tutorials. @juharr But what happens when you call itemBuilder and pass it the ReceiptItemBuilder

Comment: It will pass your ReceiptItemBuilder to whatever function you passed in.  In the linked question an example would be `i => i.WithIngredients("Ingredients1")` which means it will end up calling `WithIngredients("Ingredients1")` on the `rib` object that is pass to the delegate.  It basically lets you inject code into a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action is a delegate type, and in C# delegate types (like `Action`, `Func` and `Predicate`, or just straight up `delegate`) are ways of passing methods around as parameters. Delegate types can be called directly by doing `itemBuilder(rib)`, this executes the Action (Method) `itemBuilder` with the parameter `rib`.

What it does is this:

First we declare the method with the Action parameter

```cs
public ReceiptBuilder WithItem(string text, Action<ReceiptItemBuilder> itemBuilder)
```

`Action<ReceiptItemBuilder>` Limits our parameter to methods that return a `void` and take one parameter of type `ReceiptItemBuilder`.

So we can now declare a method that fits these criteria. Here's mine:

```cs
public void ItemWithIngredient(ReceiptItemBuilder itemBuilder)
{
    itemBuilder.WithIngredients("Ingredients1");
}
```

And pass to `WithItem` like so:

```cs
WithItem("Item1", ItemWithIngredient);
```

Now this isn't of much use as we can't change the Ingredients, as we hardcoded it. So instead we us something called a anonymous method, and we define it with a lambda expression like so:

```cs
WithItem("Item1", i => i.WithIngredients("Ingredients1"));
```

The `i => ...` part basically declares a method and uses it. `i` here is the parameter and is of type `ReceiptItemBuilder`.

This Answer is kinda rambly and I'm bad at explaining things. I highly suggest you check out the Links posted in the comments by Olivier Rogier but here's a quick overview over the three standard delegate types:

Action: `Action` is a method that returns a void and takes no parameters. It has some Overloads like `Action<T>` which represents a method with one parameter of type `T` (replace `T` with any type you want). There are more overloads for more parameters (`Action<T1, T2>`, `Action<T1, T2, T3>` ...)

Func: `Func<T>` is a method that returns `T` and takes no parameters (there is no `Func` as Func always returns something). There are overloads for this as well, these take parameters (`Func<TInput, TOutput>`, `Func<TInput1, TInput2, TOutput>` ...)

Predicate: A `Predicate<T>` always takes one parameter and returns a `bool`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to explain this concept. You claim to be bad at explaining things but your explanation together with the other previous comments has helped make this a lot clearer for me. I realize I have a long way to go, but at least now I am not completely lost.