# How to created builder for nested objects

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, builder, builder-pattern

I am looking for a way to create a builder that can create nested objects.

I have already read this topic: [Builder pattern with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480410/builder-pattern-with-nested-objects)
but that approach is modyfing model/entities which **I'd like to avoid.**

I have few models:
**Advertisment** has an **Owner**, **Owner** has an **Address** and **Address** has a **Contact** entity.

```
public class Advertisment
{
    public string AdvertismentId { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
}
public class Owner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to chain methods like this (or something similar):

```
        var ad = new AdBuilder()
                    .WithId("123")
                    .WithOwner(x =>
                        x.WithName("NameOfOwner")
                        x.WithAddress(x => x.WithStreet("SomeStreet"))
                        .WithContact(y => y.WithPhoneNo("123-345-789"))));
```

I prepared the code here:
https://rextester.com/TRN19779

I don't want to modify models because they are generated from JSON Schema and I keep them in a separte class library. I am going to use above builder to map one object to another.
I am preparing an object to send to 3rd party consumer.

Would be someone so nice and help a bit?

Comment: It does seem to me a bit overkill to have 7 `WithXYZ` methods to set 4 properties and glue the objects together. Wouldn't it be enough to have a single method with 4 parameters that can build up the whole hierarchy and set all values?

Comment: @Peter I am also not convinced however building a bit complex object using a new operator does not convince me as well

Comment: That is just a piece of that object. The whole object I am building is much larger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using interfaces. Each sub `object` has an `interface` used to construct it. For example, the `Owner` class has the corresponding `IOwner` interface which allows the user to populate the properties of the `Owner` `class`.

```
public interface IBuild
{
    Advertisement Build( );
}

public interface IAdvertisement : IBuild
{
    IAdvertisement WithID( string id );
    IAdvertisement WithOwner( Action<IOwner> func );
}

public interface IOwner
{
    IOwner WithName( string name );
    IOwner WithAddress( Action<IAddress> func );
}

public interface IAddress
{
    IAddress WithStreet( string street );
    IAddress WithContact( Action<IContact> func );
}

public interface IContact
{
    IContact WithPhoneNumber( string phoneNumber );
}

public class AdvertisementBuilder : IAdvertisement, IOwner, IAddress, IContact
{
    private readonly Advertisement _advert = new( )
    { Owner = new( ) { Address = new( ) { Contact = new( ) } } };

    private AdvertisementBuilder( )
    { }

    public static IAdvertisement Create( ) => 
        new AdvertisementBuilder( );        

    public IOwner WithAddress( Action<IAddress> func )
    {
        func( this );
        return this;
    }

    public IAddress WithContact( Action<IContact> func )
    {
        func( this );
        return this;
    }

    public IAdvertisement WithID( string id )
    {
        _advert.AdvertisementId = id;
        return this;
    }

    public IOwner WithName( string name )
    {
        _advert.Owner.Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public IAdvertisement WithOwner( Action<IOwner> func )
    {
        func( this );
        return this;
    }

    public IContact WithPhoneNumber( string phoneNumber )
    {
        _advert.Owner.Address.Contact.PhoneNo = phoneNumber;
        return this;
    }

    public IAddress WithStreet( string street )
    {
        _advert.Owner.Address.Street = street;
        return this;
    }

    // Here you can do some validation and make sure 
    // any required information has been filled in.
    public Advertisement Build( ) => _advert;
}


static void Main( string[ ] _ )
{
    var advertisement = AdvertisementBuilder.Create( )
        .WithID( "Some id" )
        .WithOwner( o => o.WithName( "Bill" )
            .WithAddress( a => a.WithStreet( "Some street" )
            .WithContact( c => c.WithPhoneNumber( "905-334-5839" ) ) ) )
        .Build( );
}
```