# The builder pattern, delegates and lambda expression- need explanation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, lambda, delegates

I am not new in the programming world, however I need help with understanding what is going on in this code. I DO understand the builder pattern and the Action delagete (does not return anything, but can take some parameters).

What bothers me a lot is below code:

```
    0. var carBuilder = new CarBuilder().WithDoors(x => x.WithDoors(4)).Build();
    1. public CarBuilder WithDoors(Action<DoorsBuilder> x)
    2. {
    3.    var doorsBuilder = new DoorsBuilder();
    4.    x(doorsBuilder);
    5.    _car.AddDoors(doorsBuilder.Build());
    6.    return this;
    7. }
```

1. What happens in line 4?
2. What do I actually pass in line 0 to WithDoors function?
3. Is is possible to rewrite that code in some simpler way (to get better understanding :))?

Code:
https://rextester.com/SIOV54215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens in line 4?

At line 4 the code calls the action delegate passing in the `DoorBuilder` which has been created in line 3, and in line 5 it adds the doors built using the door builder to the car being built by the `CarBuilder`. This is a fairly common pattern used in composite (or nested) builders. It looks much like a similar answer I gave to a question a number of years ago: [Builder pattern with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480410/builder-pattern-with-nested-objects/38480829#38480829)

> What do I actually pass in line 0 to WithDoors function?

Herein is a problem, the naming of your methods is somewhat confusing, both the `CarBuilder` and the `DoorBuilder` has a method named `WithDoors`. I would have made the `DoorBuilder` have a method named `NumberOfDoors` making the code more readable, and more obvious what is happening:

```
var car = new CarBuilder().WithDoors(x => x.NumberOfDoors(4)).Build();
```

(Note the change of variable name; the result of this line is a (built) `car` *NOT* a `carBuilder`!)

> Is is possible to rewrite that code in some simpler way (to get better understanding :))?

I wonder whether there is even a need for a nested builder here, perhaps there is as it becomes more complicated (say, setting the features of the door such as trim, electric wondows, etc etc) but as you have it right now the only thing you can build is the number of doors which could just as easily be put on the `CarBuilder` itself making the code:

```
var car = new CarBuilder().WithDoors(4).Build();
```

Comment: Does x.Invoke(doorsBuilder) is equivalent to x(doorsBuilder)?

Comment: It looks like x.NumberOfDoors() need an instance of DoorsBuilder to have possibility to execute. 
x.NumberOfDoors of course does not take it explicitly, but implicitly. In other words: If I want to execute x.NumberOfDoors I need to provide an instance of DoorsBuilder. 
Did I get it right?

Comment: @tylkonachwile I think so, yes.

Comment: And yes, you can call delegates with `Invoke`